# Cannot print out Binary calculation

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I have a skeleton code to take the inputs of two numbers and add them together, however i don't know how to write out the part of the code to convert the inputs into a binary number

for example, if i type ./calc.c 5+5. The number is 10 and the binary is 00001010.
But i don't know how to convert the decimal into binary using code.

Any help?

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

  int dec1 = atoi(argv[1]);
  char op = argv[2][0]; 
  int dec2 = atoi(argv[3]);
  int i;


  printf("Called with dec1: %d op: %c dec2: %d\n", dec1, op, dec2);


  if(dec1 & 1){

    printf("bit is 1\n");
  }
  int sum = dec1 + dec2;

  if (op == '+'){

    for (i=0; i < 4; i++){

      printf("%d\n", i); 
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how you would convert from decimal into binary with a pencil and a piece of paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to check the value of each individual bit with a bitmask. Note that an integer is generally 4 bytes on most systems, but for the sake of your example let's only consider the rightmost 8 bits. Also, I'm going to assume that `sum` is already correctly calculated since your question is about printing an integer in binary and not parsing equations or arithmetic.

Let's make a bitmask equivalent to `10000000`, which equals 128, and then rotate it. Then we can check `sum` with a bitwise AND to see if each bit is set.

```
int bitmask = 128;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {
    if (sum & bitmask)
        printf("1");
    else
        printf("0");
    bitmask = bitmask >> 1;
}

printf("\n");
```

This solution checks each bit in `sum`, left to right, to see if it is set. If so, print a 1, otherwise, print 0. This is one way to print integers in binary.